# Spring: Bean property not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: spring, javabeans

I'm experimenting with Spring, I'm following the book: Spring: A developer's notebook. I'm getting this error:

`"Bean property 'storeName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?"`

.. and I'm quite lost.

I have an `ArrayListRentABike` class which implements `RentABike`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListRentABike implements RentABike {
    private String storeName;
    final List bikes = new ArrayList( );

    public ArrayListRentABike( ) { initBikes( ); }

    public ArrayListRentABike(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
        initBikes( );
}

public void initBikes( ) {
    bikes.add(new Bike("Shimano", "Roadmaster", 20, "11111", 15, "Fair"));
    bikes.add(new Bike("Cannondale", "F2000 XTR", 18, "22222", 12, "Excellent"));
    bikes.add(new Bike("Trek", "6000", 19, "33333", 12.4, "Fair"));
}

public String toString( ) { return "RentABike: " + storeName; }

public List getBikes( ) { return bikes; }

public Bike getBike(String serialNo) {
    Iterator iter = bikes.iterator( );
    while(iter.hasNext( )) {
        Bike bike = (Bike)iter.next( );
        if(serialNo.equals(bike.getSerialNo( ))) return bike;
    }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And my `RentABike-context.xml` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <bean id="rentaBike" class="ArrayListRentABike">
        <property name="storeName"><value>"Bruce's Bikes"</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="commandLineView" class="CommandLineView">
        <property name="rentaBike"><ref bean="rentaBike"/></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Any ideas please?
Thanks a lot! 
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the parameter passed to the constructor will initialize the `storeName`, you can use the `constructor-arg` element to set the `storeName`.

```
<bean id="rentaBike" class="ArrayListRentABike">
    <constructor-arg  value="Bruce's Bikes"/>
</bean>
```

The `constructor-arg` elements allow to pass parameters to the constructor (surprise, surprise) of your spring bean.

Answer (score 12):

You're using setter injection but don't have a setter defined for attribute `storeName`. Either add a setter/getter for `storeName` or use constructor injection.

Since you already have a constructor defined that takes `storeName` as input i'd say change your `RentABike-context.xml` to the following:

```
<bean id="rentaBike" class="ArrayListRentABike">
    <constructor-arg index="0"><value>Bruce's Bikes</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: And if property name is "myDataSource" (property name="myDataSource"), then your setter needs to be named as setMyDataSource(); not like setDataSource.

Comment: Also SPRING expects getter with same return type of the property like getMyDataSource(). And both getter/setter are should be public level accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of storeName not defined for value solution is in:

```
<bean id="rentaBike" class="ArrayListRentABike">
    <property name="storeName"><value>"Bruce's Bikes"</value></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

on this type of error some time access modifier of the field is also required to check, by chance if it is default the spring will throw the error. access modifier of the setter should be public so that spring can use it to set the property